# Add a prefix to logs with AWK

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

I am facing a problem with a script I need to use for log analysis; let me explain the question:

I have a gzipped file like:

```
5555_prova.log.gz
```

Inside the file there are mali lines of log like this one:

```
2018-06-12    03:34:31    95.245.15.135    GET    /hls.playready.vod.mediasetpremium/farmunica/2018/06/218742_163f10da04c7d2/hlsrc/w12/21.ts
```

I need a script read the gzipped log file which is capable to output on the stdout a modified log line like this one:

```
5555 2018-06-12    03:34:31    95.245.15.135    GET    /hls.playready.vod.mediasetpremium/farmunica/2018/06/218742_163f10da04c7d2/hlsrc/w12/21.ts
```

As you can see the line of log now start with the number read from the gzip file name. 
I need this new line to feed a logstash data crunching chain.

I have tried with a script like this:

```
 echo "./5555_prova.log.gz" | xargs -ISTR -t -r  sh -c "gunzip -c STR | awk '{$0="5555 "$0}' "
```

this is not exactly what I need (the prefix is static and not captured with a regular expression from the file name) but even with this simplified version I receive an error:

```
sh -c gunzip -c ./5555_prova.log.gz | awk '{-bash=5555 -bash}'
-bash}' : -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-bash}' : -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

As you can see from the above output the `$0` is no more the whole line passed via pipe to awk but is a *strange* `-bash`.

I need to use xargs because the list of gzipped file is fed the the command line from an another tool (i.e. an instantiated `inotifywait` listening to a directory where the files are written via ftp).
What I am missing? do you have some suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Regards,
S.

---

Trying to following the @Charles Duffy suggestion I have written this code:

```
#/bin/bash

#
# Usage: sendToLogstash.sh [pattern]
#
# Executes a command whenever files matching the pattern are closed in write
# mode or moved to. "{}" in the command is replaced with the matching filename (via xargs).
# Requires inotifywait from inotify-tools.
#
# For example,
#
#    whenever.sh '/usr/local/myfiles/'
#
#


DIR="$1"
PATTERN="\.gz$"

script=$(cat <<'EOF'
awk -v filename="$file" 'BEGIN{split(filename,array,"_")}{$0=array[1] OFS $0} 1' < $(gunzip -dc "$DIR/$file")
EOF
)

inotifywait -q --format '%f' -m -r -e close_write -e moved_to "$DIR" \
      | grep --line-buffered $PATTERN | xargs -I{} -r sh -c "file={}; $script"
```

But I got the error:

```
[root@ms-felogstash ~]# ./test.sh ./poppo
gzip: /1111_test.log.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: /1111_test.log.gz: No such file or directory
sh: $(gunzip -dc "$DIR/$file"): ambiguous redirect
```

Thanks for your help, I feel very lost writing bash scripts.

Regards,
S.

Comment: You have nested quotes and bash does not understand. It thinks your `"gunzip...` quote ends at `'{$0="` and gets confused because you have 1 single quote.

Comment: Your inner single quotes are literal, not syntactic, so they don't stop the `$0` from being replaced by the shell before content is passed to `awk`. (When interpreted by bash and not awk, `$0` is by convention/default the name of the current script; for an interactive interpreter, that name is `-bash`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Also in case you are dealing with multiple `.gz` files and want to print their content along with their file names(first column _ delimited) then following may help you.

```
for file in *.gz; do
    awk -v filename="$file" 'BEGIN{split(filename,array,"_")}{$0=array[1] OFS $0} 1' <(gzip -dc "$file")
done
```

---

---

I haven't tested your code(couldn't completely understand also), so trying to give here a way like in case your code could pass file name to `awk` then it will be pretty simple to append the file's first digits like as follows(just an example).

```
awk 'FNR==1{split(FILENAME,array,"_")} {$0=array[1] OFS $0} 1' 5555_prova.log_file
```

So here I am taking `FILENAME` out of the box variable for `awk`(only in first line of file) and then by splitting it into array named array and then adding it in each line of the file.

Also wrap `"gunzip -c STR` this with ending `"` which seems to be missing before you pass its output to `awk` too.

Answer (score 2):

**NEVER, EVER** use `xargs -I` with a string substituted into `sh -c` (or `bash -c` or any other context where that string is interpreted as code). This allows malicious filenames to run arbitrary commands -- think about what happens if someone runs `touch $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\'.gz'`, and gets that file into your log.

Instead, let `xargs` append arguments *after* your script text, and write your script to iterate over / read those arguments as data, rather than having them substituted into code.

---

To show how to use `xargs` safely (well, safely *if* we assume that you've filtered out filenames with literal newlines):

```
# This way you don't need to escape the quotes in your script by hand
script=$(cat <<'EOF'
for arg; do gunzip -c <"$arg" | awk '{$0="5555 "$0}'; done
EOF
)

# if you **did** want to escape them by hand, it would look like this:
#   script='for arg; do gunzip -c <"$arg" | awk '"'"'{$0="5555 "$0}'"'"'; done'

echo "./5555_prova.log.gz" | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c "$script" _
```

To be safer with *all possible* filenames, you'd instead use:

```
printf '%s\0' "./5555_prova.log.gz" | xargs -0 sh -c "$script" _
```

Note the use of NUL-delimited input (created with `printf '%s\0'`) and `xargs -0` to consume it.

Comment: I'd need the actual error to say anything. If it doesn't fit cleanly into a comment, could you perhaps post the exact code of your attempt, and the error, at https://gist.github.com/?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing the comment and the message fired incomplete.
I will add the code to my Message..

Comment: The code in your edit is explicitly contrary to my advice here, where I advised you **never under any circumstances** to substitute filenames into strings parsed as code. `file={}` is precisely that substitution.

Comment: Also, when your code contains things like `<(...)`, which are bash syntax, you need to use `bash -c`, not `sh -c`.

Comment: A less-incorrect implementation would look like https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/9641c83483e0b2a8a9ea0465cc33271b. Note also that we have to `export dir` before it can be seen by the child process invoked by `bash -c` or `sh -c`.

Comment: Thanks for the help,
I know my code is against your suggestions but I wasn't able to follow your guidance. 
I have tried your "example.sh" but nothing is printed on stdout.

Comment: *shrug*. I'd need a [mcve] to speak to reproduction. If you replace the `inotifywait` bits with an `echo` and the `xargs -d $'\n' bash -c "$script"` bits work, then obviously the answer is correct insofar as it's pertinent.

Comment: ...actually, it looks like another thing I copied-and-pasted from your attempt was wrong as well -- I thought you'd written `< <(gzip ...)`, which would actually be expected to *work*, but instead you'd written `< $(gzip -dc ...)`, which is expecting to decompress the file to receive *a single filename*, and then feed awk from the file named by the contents of the gzip file. Obviously, if Ravinder's answer (which assumes the gzip files are directly the input for awk, vs each containing a compressed single filename) works, that expectation is not met.

Comment: BTW, if you want to debug execution, change `bash -c` to `bash -xc` and follow the list of commands written on stderr.